# SQL Server - update column based on another column value

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, insert-update

How can I update a column in `TableA` value found in another table, `Table B`, depending on another column, `Type`, in `TableA`

E.g.

**Table A**

```
Location Type Value
  USA    Dog   20
  UK     Cat   30
```

**Table B**

```
Dog   Cat Rabbit
 50   70    100
```

Logic:

- If `tableA.Value = Dog` then update `TableA.Value = TableB.Dog`
- If `tableA.Value = Cat` then update `TableA.Value = TableB.Cat`
- If `tableA.Value = Rabbit` then update `TableA.Value = TableB.Rabbit`

Note: There is only 3 options so hard coding is ok.

Result

**Table A**

```
Location Type  Value
USA      Dog   50
UK       Cat   70
```

Answer (score 6):

How about something like

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Value = 
CASE Type
  WHEN 'DOG' then B.Dog
  WHEN 'CAT' then B.Cat
  WHEN 'RABBIT' then B.Rabbit
  ELSE Value
END
FROM TableB b
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfdddb/6)